# How to list currently not installed packages?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, apt, dpkg

I'd like to output a list of all, currently not installed, packages (they are visible in Synaptic for example) using only shell commands.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
aptitude search '!~i'
```

See the Search Term Reference in the [aptitude user's manual](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/) for details.

Answer (score 7):

From the question's tags, I assume a Debian system.

In Bash: `aptitude search '!~i'`. The list is **very** long (more than 30k lines).

It can be interesting to suppress virtual packages also: `aptitude search '!~i !~v'`

Answer (score 0):

Type the command as follows:

```
# rpm -qa > list.txt
```

with this command you can check your installed RPM list after that you can easly to find which RPM is not installed.

Comment: thanks, but I asked for a debian system...